# How to block Android app from being drawn on top of it? (Avoid Cloack&Dagger attacks)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Is there any way to tell my Android app that do not accept outside app content being drawn on top of it? Overlays,... (but of course accept application generated overlays, diglogs, toasts,...).

Specifically to avoid the kind of attacks such as Cloack and Dagger:

http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/android-hacking-technique.html?m=1

http://cloak-and-dagger.org/#Demos

Do full-screen and video apps fully avoid it? And if do, how do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `filterTouchesWhenObscured` to true. Or implement the method `onFilterTouchEventForSecurity()`.

More info here: https://blog.devknox.io/tapjacking-android-prevent/